# Migrating GWT / Datanucleus project to Google Cloud enhancer issue

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, datanucleus

I am trying to migrate GWT/Datanucleus JDO project to Google Cloud and ran into the following when trying to enhance. I didn't change anything from GAE setup:

```
DataNucleus Enhancer (version 3.1.1) : Enhancement of classes
Sep 08, 2018 3:48:29 PM org.datanucleus.util.Log4JLogger
SEVERE: L:115 > Parser error with file "file:/C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Temp/enhancer-4720720665984377371.flf" has cause 
Sep 08, 2018 3:48:29 PM org.datanucleus.util.Log4JLogger
SEVERE: L:115 > Parser error with file "file:/C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Temp/enhancer-4720720665984377371.flf" has cause 
Error reading the Meta-Data input "Content is not allowed in prolog.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

It makes sense since the file referenced (the flf file generated by DN Enhancer) is not in XML format for some reason:

```
C:\b\src\bt\sh\package.jdo
C:\b\src\bt\sr\sec\package.jdo
C:\b\war\WEB-INF\classes\bt\sh\package.jdo
C:\b\war\WEB-INF\classes\bt\sr\sec\package.jdo
```

My question is: why is enhancer generating `non-xml` then tries to read it as `xml` out of a sudden? I have latest `4.0.1` Datanucleus Eclipse Plugin. What's the solution?

Comment: "DN Enhancer" does not generate any "flf" file. It updates the bytecode of Java class files ... and that is all

Comment: It is your configuration that defines what files are read, and for some reason you have put an "flf" file in your classpath. Which, again, is nothing to do with the DN Enhancer.